# How can I use Ajax, perl and JSON easy together?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, perl, json

I am trying to make a webpage with Ajax.

Example:

1. I create a Perl/CGU file that triggers a simple post;

   File: ..test.cgi?name=Thomas

   Text back: Your name is Thomas!
2. I create a html file that can use the post, but then the page have to reload.
   I use text input and a button.

How can I use Ajax, Perl and JSON easy together?
This is how it should work together, but how?

Html + Ajax/JavaScript CALL Perl + "JSON-perl-string" RETURN-TO Ajax CONVERT-JSON -> Html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For JSON try the [CPAN JSON module](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.14/lib/JSON.pm).

For using the XMLHttpRequest I recommend these wonderful tutorials from IBM.

[Mastering Ajax, Part 1: Introduction to Ajax](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro1.html?S_TACT=105AGX08&S_CMP=EDU)

The two articles you'll probably be most interested in are these two:

[Mastering Ajax, Part 10: Using JSON for data transfer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro10/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX08&S_CMP=EDU)

[Mastering Ajax, Part 11: JSON on the server side](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro11.html?S_TACT=105AGX08&S_CMP=EDU)

You can get the entire 11 Part series [using this search link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/web/libraryview.jsp?search_by=Mastering+Ajax).

Answer (score 4):

You just need to have your application return JSON (you can just use the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) module on CPAN for this) instead of HTML. This means you need a Content-type header of application/json instead of text/html and then you need to use that JSON in your Javascript (using a Javascript library like jQuery or Prototype is your best bet here).

Answer (score 3):

jquery provides very easy ajax and JSON support with their API, It handles all of the XMLHttpRequest objects for you. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to avoid refreshing to update the page you could try remote scripting by using the XMLHttpRequest object in XML.

More on this [here](http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/ajax_page.html).

Answer (score 1):

Give the new CPAN module [Yote](http://madyote.com) a try. It binds javascript objects to perl via a JSON rpc.

Here is an example of it on the client :

**Server**

```
package Hello;
use base 'Yote::AppRoot';

sub hello {
  return "Hello World";

1;
```

**Client**

```
$.yote.init();
var hello_app = $.yote.fetch_app('Hello');

alert( hello_app.hello() );
   // outputs "Hello World"
```